# packer building amazon-chroot - simple example does not work

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vagrant, packer

I'm trying to build an Amazon AMI centos using Packer.  I am using the amazon-chroot builder.

The ami exists, but I am getting the build error

```
[root@ip-10-32-11-16 retel-base]# packer build retel-base.json 
amazon-chroot output will be in this color.

==> amazon-chroot: Gathering information about this EC2 instance...
==> amazon-chroot: Inspecting the source AMI...
==> amazon-chroot: Couldn't find root device!
Build 'amazon-chroot' errored: Couldn't find root device!

==> Some builds didn't complete successfully and had errors:
--> amazon-chroot: Couldn't find root device!

==> Builds finished but no artifacts were created.
```

---

cat retel-base.json

```
{
"variables": {
"ACCESS_KEY_ID": "{{env `ACCESS_KEY_ID`}}",
"SECRET_ACCESS_KEY": "{{env `SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`}}"
},
"builders": [{
"type": "amazon-chroot",
"access_key": "{{user `ACCESS_KEY_ID`}}",
"secret_key": "{{user `SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`}}",
"source_ami":"ami-a40df4cc",
"ami_name": "base image built with packer {{timestamp}}"
}]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be to do with a mismatch between the name of the root device and the block device mapping.

In the official CentOS AMIs, the root device is named `/dev/sda` but the block device mapping only lists `/dev/sda1`, which is apparently a partition on the root device.

The Aminator by Netflix has a similar problem with partitioned volumes: https://github.com/Netflix/aminator/issues/129

Comment: ok, so is there something I am doing wrong here?  I can try again.

Comment: In their current state, that AMI is not compatible with Packer. I don't know how to convert it to one that is. You could try a different one e.g. https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00JV9JBDS